# Generating mxn matrix from user input

Tags: arrays, function, numpy, matrix

I'm new to python and I am trying to work through some exercises introducing numpy. I have got stuck on this question:

Create a function that takes , ∈ ℕ as input and generates a × matrix (numpy.array)  with entries `a[i,j] = j*m + i` where 0 ≤  ≤ −1 and 0 ≤  ≤−1

I have found a way of doing this more or less without numpy but any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to create an array using generator first and then convert it into a numpy array

```
// m, n = rows, cols
np.array([j*m + i for j in range(n) for i in range(m)]).reshape((m, n))
```

However, it is a sequence of numbers along rows so it can be more easily done as

```
np.array(range(m*n)).reshape((m, n))
```

However, for this numpy library also has an inbuilt function which is `arange`

```
np.arange(m*n).reshape((m, n))
```

Hope it helps.